# Extracting just Month and Year separately from Pandas Datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe, `df`, with the following column:

```
     ArrivalDate
936   2012-12-31
938   2012-12-29
965   2012-12-31
966   2012-12-31
967   2012-12-31
968   2012-12-31
969   2012-12-31
970   2012-12-29
971   2012-12-31
972   2012-12-29
973   2012-12-29
```

The elements of the column are `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` type. I want to extract the year and month.

Here's what I've tried:

```py
df['ArrivalDate'].resample('M', how = 'mean')
```

which throws the following error:

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Then I tried:

```py
df['ArrivalDate'].apply(lambda(x):x[:-2])
```

which throws the following error:

```
'Timestamp' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My current solution is

```py
df.index = df['ArrivalDate']
```

Then, I can resample another column using the index.

But I'd still like a method for reconfiguring the entire column.  Any ideas?

Comment: the best answer is clearly.. df['mnth_yr'] = df.date_column.dt.to_period('M') as below from @jaknap32

Comment: You don't even have to do `to_period`: `df.date_column.dt.month` (or `.year`, or `.day`) works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas extract year from datetime --- df\['year'\] = df\['date'\].year is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405413/python-pandas-extract-year-from-datetime-dfyear-dfdate-year-is-not)

Comment: @elphz: `.dt.month` loses the year though. And `.dt.to_period('M')` changes the data type to something which is not a datetime64 anymore. I ended up using [Juan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561379/1026) suggesting `.astype('datetime64[M]')` to truncate the values.

Comment: Can you change the best answer?

Answer (score 611, accepted):

If you want new columns showing year and month separately you can do this:

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ArrivalDate']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ArrivalDate']).month
```

or...

```
df['year'] = df['ArrivalDate'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['ArrivalDate'].dt.month
```

Then you can combine them or work with them just as they are.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a single line ? I want to avoid traversing the same column multiple times.

Comment: Some quick benchmarking with `timeit` suggests that the `DatetimeIndex` approach is significantly faster than either `.map/.apply` or `.dt`.

Comment: the best answer is clearly.. df['mnth_yr'] = df.date_column.dt.to_period('M') as below from @jaknap32

Comment: what actually does pd.Datetimeindex do?

Comment: I sometimes do this: 
`df['date_column_trunc'] = df[date_column'].apply(lambda s: datetime.date(s.year, s.month, 1)`

Comment: This doesn't work for me - if I do this, then I get only null (NaN) returned.
and if I do `due_month = pd.DatetimeIndex(model_data['Due Date']).month` , then I can't concatenate it to a dataframe.

Comment: When I use the first method I get a SettingWithCopyWarning. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 371):

The `df['date_column']` has to be in date time format.

```
df['month_year'] = df['date_column'].dt.to_period('M')
```

You could also use `D` for Day, `2M` for 2 Months etc. for different sampling intervals, and in case one has time series data with time stamp, we can go for granular sampling intervals such as `45Min` for 45 min, `15Min` for 15 min sampling etc.

Comment: Note that the resulting column is not of the `datetime64` dtype anymore. Using `df.my_date_column.astype('datetime64[M]')`, as in [@Juan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561379/1026) converts to dates representing the first day of each month.

Answer (score 165):

You can directly access the `year` and `month` attributes, or request a `datetime.datetime`:

```
In [15]: t = pandas.tslib.Timestamp.now()

In [16]: t
Out[16]: Timestamp('2014-08-05 14:49:39.643701', tz=None)

In [17]: t.to_pydatetime() #datetime method is deprecated
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 5, 14, 49, 39, 643701)

In [18]: t.day
Out[18]: 5

In [19]: t.month
Out[19]: 8

In [20]: t.year
Out[20]: 2014
```

One way to combine year and month is to make an integer encoding them, such as: `201408` for August, 2014. Along a whole column, you could do this as:

```
df['YearMonth'] = df['ArrivalDate'].map(lambda x: 100*x.year + x.month)
```

or many variants thereof.

I'm not a big fan of doing this, though, since it makes date alignment and arithmetic painful later and especially painful for others who come upon your code or data without this same convention. A better way is to choose a day-of-month convention, such as final non-US-holiday weekday, or first day, etc., and leave the data in a date/time format with the chosen date convention.

The `calendar` module is useful for obtaining the number value of certain days such as the final weekday. Then you could do something like:

```
import calendar
import datetime
df['AdjustedDateToEndOfMonth'] = df['ArrivalDate'].map(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime(
        x.year,
        x.month,
        max(calendar.monthcalendar(x.year, x.month)[-1][:5])
    )
)
```

If you happen to be looking for a way to solve the simpler problem of just formatting the datetime column into some stringified representation, for that you can just make use of the [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/) function from the `datetime.datetime` class, like this:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
            date_time
0 2014-10-17 22:00:03

In [6]: df.date_time
Out[6]: 
0   2014-10-17 22:00:03
Name: date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [7]: df.date_time.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
Out[7]: 
0    2014-10-17
Name: date_time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Performance can be bad, so it's always good to make the best possible use of helper functions, vectorized operations, and `pandas` split-apply-combine techniques. My suggestions above aren't meant to be taken as an endorsement that they are the most performant approaches for your case -- just that they are stylistically valid Pythonic choices for a range of cases.

Comment: The answer below by @KieranPC is much much faster

Comment: the best answer is clearly.. df['mnth_yr'] = df.date_column.dt.to_period('M') as below from @jaknap32

Comment: You're supposed to multiply by 100 in `df['YearMonth'] = df['ArrivalDate'].map(lambda x: 1000*x.year + x.month)`.

Answer (score 50):

If you want the month year unique pair, using apply is pretty sleek.

```
df['mnth_yr'] = df['date_column'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B-%Y'))
```

Outputs month-year in one column.

Don't forget to first change the format to date-time before, I generally forget.

```
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'])
```

Comment: You can avoid the lambda function as well: `df['month_year'] = df['date_column'].dt.strftime('%B-%Y')`

Answer (score 33):

**SINGLE LINE: Adding a column with 'year-month'-paires:**
*('pd.to_datetime' first changes the column dtype to date-time before the operation)*

```
df['yyyy-mm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Accordingly for an extra 'year' or 'month' column:

```
df['yyyy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate']).dt.strftime('%Y')
df['mm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate']).dt.strftime('%m')
```

Comment: .dt.strftime('%Y-%m') is incredibly slow especially on millions of records compared to slicing and adding as in  ```.dt.year + "-" + .dt.month```

Comment: Alright, that a useful insight. I used it for some files of 100000 rows and it was doing just fine, but it's a useful alternative.

Answer (score 13):

You can first convert your date strings with [pandas.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), which gives you access to all of the [numpy datetime and timedelta](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html) facilities. For example:

```
df['ArrivalDate'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate'])
df['Month'] = df['ArrivalDate'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
```

Comment: This worked really well for me, as I was looking for functionality analogous to pyspark's [`trunc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=date#pyspark.sql.functions.trunc). Is there any documentation for the `astype('datetime64[M]')` convention?

Comment: I was using 'datetime[M]' as suggested for some time, but as I've updated some libs (pandas to 1.5 and some others) I've noticed that it does not truncate anymore. Now is being converted to a date.

Answer (score 10):

[@KieranPC's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149272/9209546) is the correct approach for Pandas, but is not easily extendible for arbitrary attributes. For this, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) within a generator comprehension and combine using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
# input data
list_of_dates = ['2012-12-31', '2012-12-29', '2012-12-30']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ArrivalDate': pd.to_datetime(list_of_dates)})

# define list of attributes required    
L = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'dayofweek', 'dayofyear', 'weekofyear', 'quarter']

# define generator expression of series, one for each attribute
date_gen = (getattr(df['ArrivalDate'].dt, i).rename(i) for i in L)

# concatenate results and join to original dataframe
df = df.join(pd.concat(date_gen, axis=1))

print(df)

  ArrivalDate  year  month  day  dayofweek  dayofyear  weekofyear  quarter
0  2012-12-31  2012     12   31          0        366           1        4
1  2012-12-29  2012     12   29          5        364          52        4
2  2012-12-30  2012     12   30          6        365          52        4
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to [jaknap32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206377/1982951), I wanted to aggregate the results according to Year and Month, so this worked:

```
df_join['YearMonth'] = df_join['timestamp'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y%m'))
```

Output was neat:

```
0    201108
1    201108
2    201108
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['year_month']=df.datetime_column.apply(lambda x: str(x)[:7])
```

This worked fine for me, didn't think pandas would interpret the resultant string date as date, but when i did the plot, it knew very well my agenda and the string year_month where ordered properly... gotta love pandas!

Answer (score 0):

> Then I tried:

```
df['ArrivalDate'].apply(lambda(x):x[:-2])
```

I think here the proper input should be string.

```
df['ArrivalDate'].astype(str).apply(lambda(x):x[:-2])
```

Comment: This is a solution that works, but its error prone. best is to use the already available libraries for date and time

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ArrivalDate` is already a `datetime64[ns]` dtype column (if not convert by using `pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate'])`),

- If you fancy a fast method, use numpy (faster than the pandas equivalent due to smaller overhead):<sup>1</sup>

  ```py
  df['year'] = df['ArrivalDate'].to_numpy('datetime64[Y]').view('int64') + 1970
  df['month'] = df['ArrivalDate'].to_numpy('datetime64[M]').view('int64') % 12 + 1
  ```
- If you fancy a one-liner, use `timetuple()`:<sup>2</sup>

  ```py
  df[['year', 'month']] = df['ArrivalDate'].apply(lambda x: x.timetuple()[:2]).tolist()

  # or use a list comprehension
  df[['year', 'month']] = [x.timetuple()[:2] for x in df['ArrivalDate'].tolist()]
  ```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The underlying numpy array of pandas' `datetime64[ns]` column may be accessed in a particular dtype such as `datetime64[Y]` using the `.to_numpy()` method. Once converted into a numpy array, it may be viewed as number of years since UNIX Epoch using `.view('int64')`, so adding 1970 to the result produces the correct year. Similarly, the `datetime64[ns]` column may be converted into the number of months since the UNIX Epoch using a combination of `to_numpy()`+`view()` using the correct dtypes. Then since we want to find the month, we take the remainder after dividing by 12 and add 1.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Pandas' `Timestamp` objects are equivalent to Python's `datetime` objects, so it also defines `.timetuple()` method which returns a namedtuple whose first two elements are year and month, so slicing the first two elements should do the trick.</sub>