# pandas extract year from datetime: df['year'] = df['date'].year is not working

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, extract, dataframe

I import a dataframe via `read_csv`, but for some reason can't extract the year or month from the series `df['date']`, trying that gives `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'`:

```
date    Count
6/30/2010   525
7/30/2010   136
8/31/2010   125
9/30/2010   84
10/29/2010  4469

df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', parse_dates=True)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['year'] = df['date'].year
df['month'] = df['date'].month
```

UPDATE:
and when I try solutions with `df['date'].dt` on my pandas version 0.14.1, I get   "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt' ":

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv',parse_dates=True)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
```

Sorry for this question that seems repetitive - I expect the answer will make me feel like a bonehead... but I have not had any luck using answers to the similar questions on SO.

---

FOLLOWUP: I can't seem to update my pandas 0.14.1 to a newer release in my Anaconda environment, each of the attempts below generates an invalid syntax error. I'm using Python 3.4.1 64bit.

```
conda update pandas

conda install pandas==0.15.2

conda install -f pandas
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is year coming from? Are you trying to access a row `(df["date"][0].year`?

Comment: I have a csv file with dates and other columns which all came out of SQL as string data. Trying to create new year and month columns to use for grouping. the csv has ~5000 rows.

Comment: Yes but the `df["date"]` is a `'pandas.core.series.Series'` object.  what should `df['date'].year` be?

Comment: I just want to create 2 more columns... one for year and one for month as integers.

Comment: tried df['date'].dt.year as well, EdChum.

Comment: see my update, it should work in your version of pandas, can you post which version you're using

Comment: The [**`.dt` accessor for datetime functionality was new in pandas 0.15.0** (Oct 2014)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-dt). So it ain't gonna work in 0.14.1, you must update. The footnote about Anaconda update is a separate question, recommend deleting it, conda is a different beast and well covered by other Q&A.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you're running a recent-ish version of pandas then you can use the datetime accessor [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to access the datetime components:

```
In [6]:

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'], df['month'] = df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month
df
Out[6]:
        date  Count  year  month
0 2010-06-30    525  2010      6
1 2010-07-30    136  2010      7
2 2010-08-31    125  2010      8
3 2010-09-30     84  2010      9
4 2010-10-29   4469  2010     10
```

**EDIT**

It looks like you're running an older version of pandas in which case the following would work:

```
In [18]:

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'], df['month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year), df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df
Out[18]:
        date  Count  year  month
0 2010-06-30    525  2010      6
1 2010-07-30    136  2010      7
2 2010-08-31    125  2010      8
3 2010-09-30     84  2010      9
4 2010-10-29   4469  2010     10
```

Regarding why it didn't parse this into a datetime in `read_csv` you need to pass the ordinal position of your column (`[0]`) because when `True` it tries to parse columns `[1,2,3]` see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
In [20]:

t="""date   Count
6/30/2010   525
7/30/2010   136
8/31/2010   125
9/30/2010   84
10/29/2010  4469"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', parse_dates=[0])
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date     5 non-null datetime64[ns]
Count    5 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```

So if you pass param `parse_dates=[0]` to `read_csv` there shouldn't be any need to call `to_datetime` on the 'date' column after loading.

Answer (score 17):

This works:

```
df['date'].dt.year
```

Now:

```
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
```

gives this data frame:

```
        date  Count  year  month
0 2010-06-30    525  2010      6
1 2010-07-30    136  2010      7
2 2010-08-31    125  2010      8
3 2010-09-30     84  2010      9
4 2010-10-29   4469  2010     10
```

Answer (score 7):

#### When to use `dt` accessor

A common source of confusion revolves around when to use **`.year`** and when to use **`.dt.year`**.

The former is an attribute for [`pd.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) objects; the latter for [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html) objects. Consider this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01', '2018-10-20', '2018-12-25'])},
                  index=pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03']))
```

The definition of the series and index look similar, but the `pd.DataFrame` constructor converts them to different types:

```
type(df.index)     # pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
type(df['Dates'])  # pandas.core.series.Series
```

The `DatetimeIndex` object has a direct `year` attribute, while the `Series` object must use the `dt` accessor. Similarly for `month`:

```
df.index.month               # array([1, 1, 1])
df['Dates'].dt.month.values  # array([ 1, 10, 12], dtype=int64)
```

A subtle but important difference worth noting is that `df.index.month` gives a NumPy array, while `df['Dates'].dt.month` gives a Pandas series. Above, we use [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) to extract the NumPy array representation.

Answer (score 5):

Probably already too late to answer but since you have already parse the dates while loading the data, you can just do this to get the day

```
df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was upgrading pandas to latest version:

From Command Line do:

```
conda update pandas
```