# python - trying to get a new pandas release

Tags: python, pandas, version, release

I am currently using pandas 0.14.1 with Spyder 2.3.1 and Python 3.4 --- is there an easy way to get an updated pandas release?

This is a follow up question from a post I made last week: 
[python pandas extract year from datetime --- df['year'] = df['date'].year is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405413/python-pandas-extract-year-from-datetime-dfyear-dfdate-year-is-not)

Thanks!

Comment: Use pip, `pip install -U pandas` ?

Comment: That depends on how you installed it

Comment: John Galt - in iPython, type  "pip install _U pandas"  ?

Comment: I see on other page you are using anaconda/conda which is generally good.  In one of your commands I notice you have `==` instead of `=` which could be a problem.  This would be a good question to ask on the anaconda mailing list:  https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda

Comment: `pip` and `conda` commands should be typed at your system prompt, not from within ipython.  That might be your problem...

Comment: JohnE - pretty embarrassing, that was the issue. i was in ipython. thank you.

Comment: No worries, the documentation is often not explicit about where to enter those commands, so it's easy to do that and not uncommon.  That's also why it can be helpful to include the actual error message in the question and then somebody might figure it out sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer pip to sovle this. Maybe easy_install can work too.

Comment: why do you prefer pip?