# Create hour of day from DF index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF with datetime index.

```
Created_Ts           value        
2001-01-01 06:00:00  199
2001-01-01 06:15:00  299
2001-01-01 07:30:00  399
2001-01-01 07:45:00  400
```

I want to create the hour of the day from the datetime index.

Current Approach:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df["hour"] = df["Created_Ts"].dt.hour
```

It works, but is there a pandas way to create the hour column directly and without resetting the index

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113327/9209546) on the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index` and remove `.dt`:

```
df["hour"] = df.index.hour
```