# Get month from date column

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, series

I need to extract the month from "datetime" column in my database and put it in a seperate column for each row. I tried code below and many others.

```
df3['DatumTijdOverlijden'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['DatumTijdOverlijden'],
                                            format='"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"')

for x in df3['DatumTijdOverlijden']:
    a = 'DatumTijdOverlijden'
    datee = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)
    df3.set_value(y, 'Month', datee)
    y+=1
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-from-pandas-datetime-column-python

Answer (score 18):

You don't need a loop for this task. Just extract `pd.Series.dt.month` attribute from your `datetime` series. If you need your month as a string, you can use the `pd.Series.dt.strtime` method. Here are some examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['05-01-2018', '02-20-2020']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Month-str'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df['Month-str-full'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B')

print(df)

        Date  Month Month-str Month-str-full
0 2018-05-01      5       May            May
1 2020-02-20      2       Feb       February
```