# using query with a tuple column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas df that has one of the columns as a tuple. I would like to use `query` to subset the df using the first entry of the tuple. What's the best way to do this? I'm on pandas .23.3, Python 3.6.6

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": list(zip(range(9), range(9)[::-1]))})
df.query("val[0] > 3") #this line does not work!
```

I know that I can split the column up and then subset but I don't want to split it up.

**update**: for anyone who decides to go the route of unpacking the tuple and having two separate columns, here is a simple way to do this:

```
df["a"], df["b"] = list(zip(*df.val.tolist()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your queries are more complicated than "val > 3". This is one easy way to get the first item from your column—with the `.str` accessor:

```
df.val.str[0].to_frame().query('val > 3')

   val
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
```

The reason this works is because `.str` will work with any object column (this includes columns of lists and tuples), not just strings (strings are considered objects, one of many possible types).
If `query` is not a necessity, this will be good enough:

```
v = df.val.str[0]
v[v > 3]

   val
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
```

There's also

```
pd.DataFrame({'val' : [v[0] for v in df['val']}).query('val > 3')

   val
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
```

Which uses a list comprehension to build a new single columned DataFrame from scratch. This should be the fastest, but I would prefer one of the approaches above.

Comment: they are more complicated but this is interesting: how come `df.val.str[0]` returns int type rather than string?

Comment: @Alex `df.str` works on any object column (including lists and tuples), not just string (strings are considered objects too).

Comment: oh i see so `.str` will simply return a series of objects in the `val` column and then you can you any method available on that object? (ie `__getitem__` in this case)

Comment: @Alex it returns a series, so all series methods are applicable here. For performance, you may want to do an astype(int) conversion because the output of .str[] is an object column.

Comment: ok cool, this is good to know. my df obviously contains other columns but i just wanted to filter by the column that contains tuples, hence the reason for doing query. i suppose then i'll just boolean select the df using your method. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way to do this?

In my opinion, don't work with a series of tuples to begin with. This negates one of the main benefits of Pandas: vectorised computations with NumPy arrays.

Instead, you can split your series of tuples into two series of integers. Then use `pd.DataFrame.query` as usual:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['val'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('val')

print(df.query('val0 > 3'))

   val0  val1
4     4     4
5     5     3
6     6     2
7     7     1
8     8     0
```

Comment: yes, i think you may be right: my tuple contains (year, month) values but i think it may just be best to have them in separate columns

Comment: just remembered why i never split up year and month: if i want to select all elements less than a particular year and month i can't do "year < my_year & month < my_month", becomes very ugly when cols are split up

Comment: Well, you can `df.query('year < 2010 & month < 5')` or `df[(df['year'] < 2010) & (df['month'] < 5)]`.

Comment: no that won't work: say the year is 2010 and month 5, and i want all sample points before. while year < 2010 will be true, the sample point in 2009-12 will fail since 12 > 5

Comment: in R i represent year month points as integers of the form YYYYMM. i suppose i can do the same in pandas

Comment: @Alex, I see what you mean now. There is a solution, which is to use `datetime` [probably give up on `query` at this point], then use either the first or last day of each month. As long as you are consistent in your convention, you can then query like `df.loc[df['datetime'] < '2010-05-01']`, etc. [Or you can try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43896119/9209546).