# Check whether tuple column in pandas contains some value from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a tuple column. I would like a mask identifying for each row whether any of the values in the tuple column matches any value in a predetermined tuple. My attempt is below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': (2, 3, 4)}, {'a': 5, 'b': (6, 7, 8)}])
print(df)

codes = (3, 4, 20, 22)
mask = df.b.str.contains_any(codes)  # This line is incorrect
```

Desired output:

```
0     True
1    False
```

I was hopeful based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689894/10499953 that str functions would work for tuples, but I couldn't get that to work for even a single value from `codes`:

```
a = df['has_code'] = df['b'].str.contains(4)
```

gives

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection` and use `astype(bool)`

```
code = set(codes)
df.b.map(code.intersection).astype(bool)

0     True
1    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Timeit analysis

```
#setup
o = [np.random.randint(0,10,(3,)) for _ in range(10_000)]
len(o)
# 10000

s = pd.Series(o)
s
0       [6, 2, 5]
1       [7, 4, 0]
2       [1, 8, 2]
3       [4, 8, 9]
4       [7, 3, 4]
          ...
9995    [3, 9, 4]
9996    [6, 2, 9]
9997    [2, 0, 5]
9998    [5, 0, 7]
9999    [7, 4, 2]
Length: 10000, dtype: object
```

---

```
# Adam's answer
In [38]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: any(set(x).intersection(codes)))
19.1 ms ± 193 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#komatiraju's answer
In [39]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: any(val in x for val in codes))
83.8 ms ± 974 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#My answer
In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: code = set(codes)
    ...: s.map(code.intersection).astype(bool)
    ...:
    ...:
15.5 ms ± 300 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#wwnde's answer
In [74]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x:len([*{*x}&{*codes}])>0)
19.5 ms ± 372 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For `Series` of size 1 million

```
bigger_o = np.repeat(o,100,axis=0)
bigger_o.shape
# (1000000, 3)
s = pd.Series((list(bigger_o)))
s
0         [6, 2, 5]
1         [6, 2, 5]
2         [6, 2, 5]
3         [6, 2, 5]
4         [6, 2, 5]
            ...
999995    [7, 4, 2]
999996    [7, 4, 2]
999997    [7, 4, 2]
999998    [7, 4, 2]
999999    [7, 4, 2]
Length: 1000000, dtype: object
```

---

```
In [54]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: any(set(x).intersection(codes)))
1.89 s ± 28.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [55]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: any(val in x for val in codes))
8.9 s ± 652 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [56]: %%timeit
    ...: code = set(codes)
    ...: s.map(code.intersection).astype(bool)
    ...:
    ...:
1.54 s ± 4.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [79]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x:len([*{*x}&{*codes}])>0)
1.95 s ± 88.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: codes should really be a set anyway, based on my use case. This works well.

Comment: @AttilatheFun Yes, set suits your use-case. Glad this helped. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
res = df['b'].apply(lambda x: any(val in x for val in codes))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
0     True
1    False
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option

```
df['b'].apply(lambda x: any(set(x).intersection(codes)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.b.apply(lambda x:len([*{*x}&{*codes}])>0)#my preferred speed wise
#df.b.apply(lambda x:[*{*x}&{*codes}]).str.len()>0 #Works as well

0     True
1    False
Name: b, dtype: bool

%timeit df.b.apply(lambda x:len([*{*x}&{*codes}])>0)
220 µs ± 2.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%%timeit 

code = set(codes)
df.b.map(code.intersection).astype(bool)
364 µs ± 1.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['b'].apply(lambda x: any(val in x for val in codes))
210 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['b'].apply(lambda x: any(set(x).intersection(codes)))
211 µs ± 1.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Added timeit results ;)

Comment: done, just added

Comment: You should always benchmark with larger size dataframes. Then you observe how each of the proposed solution works, for example, my solution is slower than all of the proposed solution for small data, but faster when used with larger data. komatiraju's solution works well with small data but when used with large data it's almost 8X slower.

Comment: interesting gained no vote