# Subset pandas dataframe based on date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in my pandas dataframe which I convert to datetime first and then extract the year:

```
data[date]      = pd.to_datetime(data[date])
data['year'] = pd.PeriodIndex(data[date], freq='A')
```

I would like to subset this based on the year, something like:

```
 if data['year'] ==2015
```

But somehow that does not work. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Show a complete piece of code that makes sense, not a single "if" condition with the note "that does not work".  Be specific.  If you got an error message, post it.  Include sample input and desired output.

Comment: a sample from the data would help. generally, you could try `data[data['date'].dt.year == 2015]`

Comment: data[data['year'].dt.year worked!! Thank you so much

Comment: John, you are right, I will be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic methods to solve this.

If you want to make a new column named `year` to solve this, then you can take the year from the date column and create `year` column, on which you can do `loc` and get the needed result.

It can be done like this.

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['year'] = data['date'].dt.year

data.loc[data.year == 2015, :]
```

If you don't want to make a seperate column for solving this you can directly access the year from the date feature on `loc`. It can be done like this.

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.loc[data.date.dt.year == 2015, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the rows where `year` equals `2015` from your dataframe, the right pandas syntax would be:

```
data[data['year'] == 2015]
```

OR

```
data[data.year == 2015]
```

### Note:

Please ensure that the `year` column is of type `int`. It may be the case that you forgot to convert the `year` to `int` in which case it is most likely going to be a `str`ing. In such a case, use:

```
data[data['year'] == '2015']
```

OR

```
data[data.year == 2015]
```

Alernatively, if you just need the subset where the year is 2015 without needing a column for the year, you can do.

```
data[pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date']).year == 2015]
```

Comment: So both cases 2015 and '2015' come back empty

Comment: I think you did not extract the year from the date correctly. Please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-from-pandas-datetime-column-python). I would go for @KieranPC 's answer. Ensure that the year was extracted correctly and then the code snippets that I shared above would do the rest.