# Why can't I make a column with extracted months from the 'dates' column in my DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe with dates, and I want to make a column with only the month of the corresponding date in each row. First, I converted my dates to ts objects like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

After that, I tried to make my new column for the month like this:

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].month
```

However, it gives me an error:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'

I do not understand why I can't do it like this. I double checked whether the conversion to ts objects actually works, and that does work. Also, if I extract 1 date using slicing, I can append .month to get the month. I technically could solve the problem by looping over all indices and then slicing for each index, but my dataframe contains 166000+ rows so that is not an option.

Comment: Use `df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149272/2901002) answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use property (or accessor object) [dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

`df["month"] = df.date.dt.month`