# Convert an n x 1 dataframe to an a x b sized grid based on month, year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime index that I'd like to reorient as a grid from a pandas time-series dataframe.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
DATE        VAL         
2007-06     0.008530
2007-07    -0.067069
2007-08     0.026660
2007-09     0.016237
2007-10     0.025145
2007-11    -0.063666
2007-12    -0.002118
2008-01    -0.059951
2008-02    -0.033422
2008-03     0.008978
2008-04     0.039997
2008-05     0.043563
2008-06    -0.076166
...
```

And I'd like to reorient, with `[year]` rows and `[month]` columns, to look like this:

```
      Jan       Feb      Mar    ...  Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec  
2007   0         0        0     ... .008530  -.067069 .026660  .016237  .025145  -.06366  -.025145 
2008  -.05995  -.033422 .00897  ... -.076166   ...
...
```

reshape/stack/unstack methods appear to do a version what I'd like, but as I have a single date index, these don't lend themselves to my dataframe.

Comment: Possibly answer already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi, not quite...the year and month values are available via `year` and `month` methods applied to the index, but that doesn't really help absent an application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert `DATE` to datetimes and reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), for months use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html). Last change order of columns names by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and remove index namd columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
m = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df1 = (df.set_index([df['DATE'].dt.year, df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%b')])['VAL']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(columns=m)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df1)
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul  \
2007  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.008530 -0.067069   
2008 -0.059951 -0.033422  0.008978  0.039997  0.043563 -0.076166  0.000000   

          Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec  
2007  0.02666  0.016237  0.025145 -0.063666 -0.002118  
2008  0.00000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and for correct ordering is used [ordered categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html)s:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
m = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df1 = (df.assign(m = pd.Categorical(df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%b'), ordered=True, categories=m),
               y = df['DATE'].dt.year)
         .pivot('y','m','VAL')
         .fillna(0)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

print (df1)
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul  \
2007  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.008530 -0.067069   
2008 -0.059951 -0.033422  0.008978  0.039997  0.043563 -0.076166  0.000000   

          Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec  
2007  0.02666  0.016237  0.025145 -0.063666 -0.002118  
2008  0.00000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Solution with `rename` columns:

```
d = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun',
     7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}
df1 = (df.set_index([df.index.year, df.index.month]).VAL
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns=d))
```

Comment: Great.  Reindexing (as in the first example) was throwing things off, so I ditched it and added naming differently.  Following works:  `df = df.set_index([df.index.year, df.index.month]).VAL.unstack(fill_value=0)
    
    df.rename(
            columns={1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr',
                     5: 'May', 6: 'Jun', 7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug',
                     9: 'Sep', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'},
            inplace=True
        )`

Comment: @Chris - yop, only remove `inplace=True`

Comment: need that part...simply returned to the screen otherwise

Comment: @Chris - I think it is one line, if second line then is necessary

Comment: @Chris - added new paragraph what I mean

Comment: yup, that would work.  appreciate it.   **edit**:  actually, don't even need the explicit `VAL` reference since the df consists of only the one column

Comment: @Chris - yop, agree, if always only 2 columns data should be omited, for geenral solutions with more columns is necessary.