# convert MMM yyyy into yyyy-mm in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

convert MMM yyyy into yyyy-mm in python3

so for a panda dateframe with dd mmm yyyy like

```
01 Feb 1985
```

It can be converted into yyyy-mm-dd with the following code

```
df[["date"]] = df[["date"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

output:

```
1985-02-01
```

But if i have MMM yyyy like

```
Feb 1985
```

and I would like to output as

```
1985-02
```

How can I do that?

```
df[["date"]] = df[["date"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

will output the date which i don't want

```
1985-02-01
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks for some comments. I just realized that there are NaN in the dataframe that I cannot drop. So I am trying to do a function to ingore NaN but the result is still like 1985-02-01. Any thoughts?

```
def date2int(df):

    for index, row in df.iteritems():

        try:
            t1=row.strftime('%b-%Y')
            return t1
        except ValueError:
            return None

date2int(df["date2"])
```

Comment: a similar question was answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column

Comment: `1985-02-01` is the pandas `__repr__` for the data type (`datetime`). You can force a different format like `df['date'].map('{:%Y-%m}'.format)`

Comment: I edited my post with the comment above. Still cannot resolve it after 1 hour of attempt.   @DOOM: the solution you kindly provided will hit the error message: ```AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'map'```.  ```
def date2int(df):
    
    for index, row in df.iteritems():
        
        print(row)
        
        if row is None:
            
            return None
        
        else:
        
            t1=row.map('{:%Y-%m}'.format)
        
print(date2int(df["date2"])) ```

Answer (score 0):

ok after an hour and half effort:

```
df['date2'] = df['date2'].loc[df['date2'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

return the desired output and avoid NaN to throw error messages

```
1985-02
```