# Editing the date in pandas to show year only, by column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand how I can edit the dataframe in python using pandas so I can drop everything but the year.

Example: if the date is 2014-01-01, I want it to show 2014 and drop both the month and the date. All the dates are in a single column.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Could you post an example data frame, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: What format is your data in? Are they datetime objects or strings?

Comment: The date is stored in (datetime64) format.. so far I have tried combining by the year (city_data['date_value'].combine(2014))

Comment: I think you are not the first that run into this issue, please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `numpy.datetime64` date value to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime()` and then you can extract year or month or day from it.

```
import numpy as np
date = np.datetime64('2014-01-01')
type(date)
```

Output:

```
numpy.datetime64
```

Convert this date to pandas datetime using `pd.to_datetime`.

```
date = pd.to_datetime(date)
type(date)
```

Output:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Then you can extract the year using `.year`
    date.year

Output:

```
2014
```

So, if you if you have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [np.datetime64('2014-01-01'), np.datetime64('2015-01-01'), np.datetime64('2016-01-01')]})
df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
df
```

Output:

```
   date
0  2014
1  2015
2  2016
```

Alternately, you can also do this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [np.datetime64('2014-01-01'), np.datetime64('2015-01-01'), np.datetime64('2016-01-01')]})
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y'))
df
```

Output:

```
   date
0  2014
1  2015
2  2016
```

**EDIT 1**

Group by using year when the column has date values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [np.datetime64('2014-01-01'), np.datetime64('2015-01-01'), np.datetime64('2016-01-01')]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.groupby(df.index.year).size()
```

Output:

```
date
2014    1
2015    1
2016    1
```

You can still do the same even if you have removed the month and day from the date and only have year in your column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [np.datetime64('2014-01-01'), np.datetime64('2015-01-01'), np.datetime64('2016-01-01')]})
df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
df.groupby('date').size()
```

Output:

```
date
2014    1
2015    1
2016    1
```

Comment: This is awesome! The only problem is that not all the dates are 2014-01-01. There are thousands of event that occur on any given day through the different years. There is not a way to group it by the years if I drop all the months and days?

Comment: @ChrisLoftus You can still use `df.groupby` on a column that has only date values or on a column that has only year values. See EDIT 1 above. Let me know if this is what you are expecting.