# Unable to extract date/year/quarter from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As per the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149272/6446053), extracting date/year/quarter in Pandas is as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_text': ['Jan 2020', 'May 2020', 'Jun 2020']})
df ['date'] = pd.to_datetime ( df.date_text ).dt.date
df ['year'], df ['month'],df['qtr'] = df ['date'].dt.year, df ['date'].dt.month, df ['date'].dt.quarter
```

However, the compiler return an error

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

May I know where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix it by remove the first `dt.date`

```
df ['date'] = pd.to_datetime ( df.date_text )
df ['year'], df ['month'], df['qtr'] = df ['date'].dt.year, df ['date'].dt.month, df ['date'].dt.quarter
df
Out[43]: 
  date_text       date  year  month  qtr
0  Jan 2020 2020-01-01  2020      1    1
1  May 2020 2020-05-01  2020      5    2
2  Jun 2020 2020-06-01  2020      6    2
```