# How use pandas dataframe to convert timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe:

[image]

How can I convert them as the "day of the week" and "day of the year" as new columns in the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column check this kind of question you'll find your answer

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.reservation...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope** this help you.

```
import pandas as pd

data= {'reservation':
['2015-12-31',
'2015-12-29',
'2015-02-20',
'2015-10-28',
'2015-12-15',
'2015-09-17'
]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reservation']).dt.dayofweek
df['day_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reservation']).dt.day_name()
df['day_of_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reservation']).dt.dayofyear

print(df)
```

**[Result]:**

> ```
>   reservation  day_of_week   day_name  day_of_year
> 0  2015-12-31            3   Thursday          365
> 1  2015-12-29            1    Tuesday          363
> 2  2015-02-20            4     Friday           51
> 3  2015-10-28            2  Wednesday          301
> 4  2015-12-15            1    Tuesday          349
> 5  2015-09-17            3   Thursday          260
> ```