# Convert datetime to month and year only in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in this format:

**Date/Time Opened**

2014-09-01 00:17:00

2014-09-18 18:55:00

I have converted it to datetime using below function

```
df['Date/Time Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Opened'])
```

How can I convert it to 'mm/yyyy' format so that I can plot it in a graph by frequency/count?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [Extracting just Month and Year separately from Pandas Datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Date/Time Opened'].dt.to_period('M')
```