# Seaborn - TypeError: Invalid object type at position 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
df_g_fcl.head()
Out[47]:
month_year  producttype fpd_30  fpd_90  fstpd_90
4   2020-01 FCL 70.0    10.0    10.0
11  2020-02 FCL 9.0     0.0     0.0
18  2020-03 FCL 28.0    6.0     15.0
25  2020-04 FCL 14.0    3.0     11.0
33  2020-05 FCL 10.0    4.0     14.0
```

And I want to display a chart x=month_year, y=fpd_30 with forecast.

I tried:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(21, 8))
ax = sns.lineplot(x='month_year', y='fpd_30', data=df_g_fcl)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```

which yielded:

> TypeError: Invalid object type at position 0

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue, it is plotting correctly

Comment: what is the dtype of `month_year` (or better, what does `df_g_fcl.dtypes()` give?)

Comment: Maybe you could try to convert the first column to strings? `df_g_fcl['month_year'] = df_g_fcl['month_year'].astype(str)`?

Comment: I have this same problem. @Riley my dtype for month_year is `period[M]`. I used `df["month_year"] = df["date"].dt.to_period('M')` to extract the month and year from a datetime column. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column

Comment: IIRC seaborn and matplotlib don't natively support plotting with periods.  You have a couple of alternatives.  1) convert the months to Timestamps (either beginning of month or middle of month would be options).  2) pandas has plot support for periods eg `ax = df_g_fcl.plot(x="month_year", y="fpd_30")`

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(21, 8))
ax = sns.lineplot(x=df_g_fcl['month_year'].astype(str), y=df_g_fcl['fpd_30'])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```

casting as string should help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn and Matplotlib don't natively support plotting with periods, ie discrete data. You can convert the month_year column to DateTime.

```
df_g_fcl["month_year"] = pd.to_datetime(df_g_fcl["month_year"], format='%Y-%m')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.lineplot(x='month_year', y='fpd_30', data=df_g_fcl, ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```