# How to extract month

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have date column and I need to add month column in 'mmm-yy' Format in pandas

For eg.

Date        Month
01/08/2022  Aug-22

Comment: Please dispaly usuable data also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column

Comment: Almost the same was as [this answer](/a/39206377/15497888) except use lowercase "b" and lowercase "y" for mmm-yy format. (or with the dt accessor as suggested by [this comment](/posts/comments/107562834)) `df['mnth_yr'] = df['date_column'].dt.strftime('%b-%y')`

Answer (score 0):

Hello @vishal Valanju ,

please create a month wise dictionary like this,

```
dict = {'date': {
      0: '28-01-2022  5:25:00 PM',
      1: '27-02-2022  6:25:00 PM',
      2: '30-03-2022  7:25:00 PM',
      3: '29-04-2022  8:25:00 PM',
      4: '31-05-2022  9:25:00 PM'
    },
 'date_short': {0: 'Jan-2022', 1: 'Feb-2022', 2: 'Mar-2022', 3: 'Apr-2022', 4: 'May-2022'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Happy Coding...!!

Comment: @vishal Valanju , if not clearly understand this code then you can also refer below link          https://datascientyst.com/convert-string-to-datetime-pandas/