# AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, date, indexing, split

I am trying to get the year from the index of my Dataframe.

At first I imported like this :

```
energie = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['eco2mix-regional-cons-def.csv']), sep=';', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

so I have my date in index

and I try to create a new column with the year only.

```
#Ajout d'une colonne Année

energie_2["Année"] = energie_2.index
energie_2["Année"] = energie_2.Année.apply(lambda Année : Année.split("-")[0])

batt_na = energie_2[energie_2['Stockage batterie'].notna()]
batt_na["Année"].unique()
```

In the end I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'

I'm a beginner in the python language, what solution can you propose me ?

thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: where is your data ? Always try to write a reproducible code.

Comment: Would this help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column