# Pycharm problem set (Stuck from step 3 onwards)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

1. Using the ff_monthly.csv data set https://github.com/alexpetralia/fama_french,
   use the first column as an index
   (**this contains the year and month of the data as a string**
2. Create a new column ‘Mkt’ as ‘Mkt-RF’ + ‘RF’
3. **Create two new columns** in the loaded DataFrame, ‘Month’ and ‘Year’ to
   contain the year and month of the dataset extracted **from the index column**.
4. Create a new DataFrame with columns ‘Mean’ and ‘Standard
   Deviation’ and the full set of years from (b) above.
5. Write a function which accepts (r_m,s_m) the monthy mean and standard
   deviation of a return series and returns a tuple (r_a,s_a), the annualised
   mean and standard deviation. Use the formulae: r_a = (1+r_m)^12 -1, and
   s_a = s_m * 12^0.5.
6. Loop through each year in the data, and calculate the annualised mean and
   standard deviation of the new ‘Mkt’ column, storing each in the newly
   created DataFrame. Note that the values in the input file are % returns, and
   need to be divided by 100 to return decimals (i.e the value for August 2022
   represents a return of -3.78%).
   . Print the DataFrame and output it to a csv file.

Workings so far:

import pandas as pd

ff_monthly=pd.read_csv(r"file path")

ff_monthly=pd.read_csv(r"file path",index_col=0)

Mkt=ff_monthly['Mkt-RF']+ff_monthly['RF']

ff_monthly= ff_monthly.assign(Mkt=Mkt)

df=pd.DataFrame(ff_monthly)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsRrM.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. pandas has excellent Getting Started guides. Especially [How to derivce new columns from existing ones](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html) looks like exactly what you need I can highly recommend diving into them if you want to learn about pandas :)

Comment: Thank you for the resources. However, what I am confused about is how to split an index column into two columns (i.e. 'Date' column which contains year and month as a string and split them into 'Month' and 'Year' columns.

Comment: You technically do not need to split the index. The easiest way would be to create a column `Month` by extracting the month. And then you create a second column `Year` by extracting the year.

Comment: And exactly how can I do that?

Comment: I try df[['Month','Year']] = df.Date.str.split("_", expand=True)but it said AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: I did the following:

from datetime import datetime

data_object= datetime.strptime(str(df.index), "%Y%m")

but value error occur: does not match format '%Y%m'

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to pay attention to.

1. The `Date` is the index of your `DataFrame`. This is treated in a special way compared to the normal columns. This is the reason `df.Date` gives an Attribute error. `Date` is not an Attribute, but the index. Instead try `df.index`
2. `df.Date.str.split("_", expand=True)` would work if your `Date` would look like `22_10`. However according to your picture it doesn't contain an underscore and also contains the day, so this cannot work
3. In fact the format you have is not even following any standard. In order to properly deal with that the best way would be parsing this to a proper `datetime64[ns]` type that pandas will understand with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%y%m%d')`. See the [python docu](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for supported format strings.

If all this works, it should be rather straightforward to create the columns

```
df['year'] = df.index.dt.year
```

In fact, this part has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column)