# Perform operations on elements of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy

Is there a faster/smarter way to perform operations on every element of a numpy array? What I specifically have is a list of datetime objects like, e.g.:

```
hh = np.array( [ dt.date(2000, 1, 1), dt.date(2001, 1, 1) ] )
```

To get a list of of years from that I do at the moment:

```
years = np.array( [ x.year for x in hh ] )
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? I'm thinking something like

```
hh.year
```

which obviously doesn't work.

I have a script in which I need different variations of a (much longer) array constantly (year, month, hours...). Of course I could always just define a separate array for everything but like there should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe use pandas's datetime64? Check the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648774/get-year-month-or-day-from-numpy-datetime64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you evaluate a python expression for each element, it doesn't matter whether the iteration will be done in C++ or Python. What will have weight is the python-complexity of the evaluated (in-loop) expression. This means: If your (in-loop) expression takes 1 microsec (a very simple script), it will be significantly harder than the difference between using a python iteration or a C++ iteration (you have a "marshalling" between C++ and PyObjects, and that applies to python functions as well).

For that reason, calling `vectorize` is -under the hoods- done in Python: what is called inside is python code. The idea behind `vectorize` is **not** performance, but code readability and ease of iteration: `vectorize` performs introspection (of function's parameters) and serves well for N-dimensional iterations (i.e. a `lambda x,y: x+y` automagically serves to iterate in two dimensions).

So: no, there's no "fast" way to iterate python code. The final speed that matters is the speed of your inner python code.

**Edit**: your -desired- `hh.year` looks like `hh*.year` equivalent in groovy, but even there under the hoods is the same as an in-code iteration. Comprehensions are the fastest (and equivalent) way in python. The real pity is being forced to:

```
years = np.array( [ x.year for x in hh ] )
```

(which forces you to create another provably-huge-sized) instead of letting you use any type of iterator:

```
years = np.array( x.year for x in hh )
```

**Edit** (suggestion by @Jaime): You can't construct `array` with that function from an iterator. For that, you must use:

```
np.fromiter(x.year for x in hh, dtype=int, count=len(x))
```

which lets you save the time and memory of building an intermediate array. This exact approach works for any sequence to avoid the inner-list creation (this one would be your case) **but does not work with other types of generators**, for future cases you'd need.

Comment: There is [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html), so `np.fromiter(x.year for x in hh, dtype=int, count=len(x))` is probably going to be as fast as it gets.

Comment: `ufunc` is another mechanism.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html  It doesn't speed up the iteration, but gives access to features like ndimensions and broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

Doing some benchmarking, performance is pretty similar (`vectorize` slightly slower than a list comprehension), and in my opinion `numpy.vectorize(lambda j: j.year)(hh)` (or something similar) doesn't look super elegant.