# Generate a list from another list with dates

Tags: python, datetime

So I have the following list of dates

```
list_dates=[np.datetime64('2018-06-11'),np.datetime64('2018-01-01'),
np.datetime64('2018-03-02'),np.datetime64('2018-03-11'),
np.datetime64('2018-05-19'),np.datetime64('2017-03-19'),
np.datetime64('2018-01-01'),np.datetime64('2017-05-30'),
np.datetime64('2016-08-11'),np.datetime64('2016-06-04')]
```

I would like to generate a new list only with those dates with the months of january and march.

The desired output would look something like this:

```
[np.datetime64('2018-01-01'),np.datetime64('2018-03-02'),np.datetime64('2017-03-19'),
np.datetime64('2016-03-11')]
```

I was thinking I was treating with strings  so I did this

```
 dates_selected=[x for x in list_dates if "-03-" in x ]+
                [x for x in list_dates if "-01-" in x ]
```

The problem is that I recieved an ouput indicating that:

```
TypeError: arguments of type numpy.datetime64 is not iterable
```

How could I obtain the desired ouput considering I am treating with datetime64 instead of strings?

Comment: They are strings. Nowhere in your examples are they anything other than strings; not `datetime` objects or `numpy.datetime64` objects

Comment: You *are* are treating with strings; the code you posted works just as you wish, albeit with the March dates first, since that's what you specified in your comprehensions.

Comment: Can you specify the output you are getting, and what you expected instead

Comment: Your edit has thrown the whole question into the no- [mcve] realm

Comment: Are you using Pandas at all in this project? Pandas datetimes are a bit easier to work with. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648774/get-year-month-or-day-from-numpy-datetime64) for e.g.. Seems the best method otherwise is just to cast back to a python datetime object.

Comment: e.g.: `[dt for dt in list_dates if dt.astype(object).month in (1, 3)]` (note you can also cast to a `datetime.datetime` if you have that imported already, but `object` works regardless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a round trip of [parsing and re-formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) your strings, which is going to be cleaner and more scalable.

```
from datetime import datetime

list_dates = ['2018-06-11','2018-01-01','2018-03-02','2018-12-19','2018-05-19','2017-03-19','2017-02-01','2017-05-30','2016-08-11','2016-06-04','2016-03-11','2016-01-01']

list_dts = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') for x in list_dates]

filtered = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for dt in list_dts if dt.month in (1, 3)]

# ['2018-01-01', '2018-03-02', '2017-03-19', '2016-03-11', '2016-01-01']
```

Comment: Beware of chameleon questions. They've edited since

Comment: @roganjosh ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ well I thought I figured out what they meant with that question, but apparently no.

Comment: I don't suspect you're gonna get the clarification needed to respond to the edit :/

Comment: OP's edit is now likely answerable with just a small modification to your code. See my comment on OP for e.g.