# Numpy vectorization messes up data type (2)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date

I'm having unwanted behaviour come out of `np.vectorize`, namely, it changes the datatype of the argument going into the original function. My [original question is about the general case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577442/numpy-vectorization-messes-up-data-type), and I'll use this new question to ask a more specific case.

(Why this second question? I've created this question *about a more specific case* in order to illustrate the problem - it's always easier to go from the specific to the more general. And I've created this question *seperately*, because I think it's useful to keep the general case, as well as a general answer to it (should one be found), by themselves and not 'contaminated' with thinking about solving any particular problem.)

So, a concrete example. Where I live, Wednesday is Lottery Day. So, let's start with a `pandas` dataframe with a date column with all Wednesdays this year:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='7D', periods=53)})
```

I want to see which of these possible days I'll actually play on. I don't feel particularly lucky at the beginning and end of each month, and there are some months I feel especially unlucky about. Therefore I use this function to see if a date qualifies:

```
def qualifies(dt, excluded_months = []):
    #Date qualifies, if...
    #. it's on or after the 5th of the month; and
    #. at least 5 days remain till the end of the month (incl. date itself); and
    #. it's not in one of the months in excluded_months.
    if dt.day < 5:
        return False
    if (dt + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - dt).days < 5:
        return False
    if dt.month in excluded_months:
        return False
    return True
```

I hope you realise that this example is still somewhat contrived ;) But it's closer to what I'm trying to do. I try to apply this function in two ways:

```
df['qualifies1'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: qualifies(x, [3, 8]))
df['qualifies2'] = np.vectorize(qualifies, excluded=[1])(df['date'], [3, 8])
```

As far as I know, both *should* work, and I'd prefer the latter, as the former is slow and [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code). **Edit:** I've learned that also the first is frowned upon lol.

However, only the first one succeeds, the second one fails with an `AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'day'`. And so my question is, **if there is a way to use `np.vectorize` on this function `qualifies`, which takes a datetime/timestamp as an argument.**

Many thanks!

PS: for the interested, this is `df`:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
         date  qualifies1
0  2020-01-01       False
1  2020-01-08        True
2  2020-01-15        True
3  2020-01-22        True
4  2020-01-29       False
5  2020-02-05        True
6  2020-02-12        True
7  2020-02-19        True
8  2020-02-26       False
9  2020-03-04       False
10 2020-03-11       False
11 2020-03-18       False
12 2020-03-25       False
13 2020-04-01       False
14 2020-04-08        True
15 2020-04-15        True
16 2020-04-22        True
17 2020-04-29       False
18 2020-05-06        True
19 2020-05-13        True
20 2020-05-20        True
21 2020-05-27        True
22 2020-06-03       False
23 2020-06-10        True
24 2020-06-17        True
25 2020-06-24        True
26 2020-07-01       False
27 2020-07-08        True
28 2020-07-15        True
29 2020-07-22        True
30 2020-07-29       False
31 2020-08-05       False
32 2020-08-12       False
33 2020-08-19       False
34 2020-08-26       False
35 2020-09-02       False
36 2020-09-09        True
37 2020-09-16        True
38 2020-09-23        True
39 2020-09-30       False
40 2020-10-07        True
41 2020-10-14        True
42 2020-10-21        True
43 2020-10-28       False
44 2020-11-04       False
45 2020-11-11        True
46 2020-11-18        True
47 2020-11-25        True
48 2020-12-02       False
49 2020-12-09        True
50 2020-12-16        True
51 2020-12-23        True
52 2020-12-30       False
```

Comment: 1) Vectorize is also frowned upon. Either way, you're running vanilla python code and discarding all the benefits of actual vectorization.

Comment: 2) Vectorize will attempt to convert the first argument into an array. Both `np.array(df['date'])` and `df['date'].values` have `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`

Comment: @MadPhysicist, looks like specifying `otypes=['boo']` prevents that conversion.  It's as though the `np.array(...)` conversion applies only when it is doing the implied `otype` calculation.  I also see this behavior when I test a simpler function that just prints the `dt` type.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, when doing the `otypes` calculation, `vectorize` uses `np.asarray(...).ravel()[0]` to get the first test value.  But for the main `loop` it does an `np.array(..., dtype=object)` in preparation to sending the args to `frompyfunc`.  Maybe we should file an `issue` on this.

Comment: @hpaulj. Definitely seems worthwhile, although I can't think of a better solution to doing a test-run. Perhaps deferring the type check until later would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

If using `np.vectorize` it's best to specify `otypes`.  In this case, the error is caused by the trial calculation the `vectorize` uses when `otypes` is not specified.  An alternative is to pass the Series as an object type array.

`np.vectorize` has a performance disclaimer.  `np.frompyfunc` may be faster, or even a list comprehension.

## testing *vectorize*

Let's define a simpler function - one that displays the type of the argument:

```
In [31]: def foo(dt, excluded_months=[]): 
    ...:     print(dt,type(dt)) 
    ...:     return True
```

And a smaller dataframe:

```
In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='7D', perio
    ...: ds=5)})                                                                
In [33]: df                                                                     
Out[33]: 
        date
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-08
2 2020-01-15
3 2020-01-22
4 2020-01-29
```

Testing `vectorize`.  (`vectorize` docs says using the `excluded` parameter degrades performance, so I'm using `lambda` as used by with `apply`):

```
In [34]: np.vectorize(lambda x:foo(x,[3,8]))(df['date'])                        
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-08 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-15 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-22 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-29 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
Out[34]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

That first line is the `datetime64` that gives problems.  The other lines are the orginal pandas objects.  If I specify the `otypes`, that problem goes away:

```
In [35]: np.vectorize(lambda x:foo(x,[3,8]), otypes=['bool'])(df['date'])       
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-08 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-15 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-22 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-29 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
Out[35]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

the apply:

```
In [36]: df['date'].apply(lambda x: foo(x, [3, 8]))                             
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-08 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-15 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-22 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-29 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
Out[36]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

A `datetime64` dtype is produced by wrapping the the Series in `np.array`.

```
In [37]: np.array(df['date'])                                                   
Out[37]: 
array(['2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-01-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-01-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-01-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-01-29T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Apparently `np.vectorize` is doing this sort of wrapping when performing the initial trial calculation, but not when doing the main iterations.  Specifying the `otypes` skips that trial calculation.  That trial calculation has caused problems in other SO, though this is a more obscure case.

In that past when I've tested `np.vectorize` it is slower than a more explicit iteration.  It does have a clear performance disclaimer.  It's most valuable when the function takes several inputs, and needs the benefit of broadcasting.  It's hard to justify when using only one argument.

`np.frompyfunc` underlies `vectorize`, but returns an object dtype.  Often it is 2x faster than explicit iteration on an array, though similar in speed to iteration on a list.  It seems to be most useful when creating and working with a numpy array of objects.  I haven't gotten it working in this case.

## vectorize code

The `np.vectorize` code is in `np.lib.function_base.py`.

If `otypes` is not specified, the code does:

```
        args = [asarray(arg) for arg in args]
        inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
        outputs = func(*inputs)
```

It makes each argument (here only one) into an array, and takes the first element.  And then passes that to the `func`.  As `Out[37]` shows, that will be a `datetime64` object.

## frompyfunc

To use `frompyfunc`, I need to convert the dtype of `df['date']`:

```
In [68]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:foo(x,[3,8]), 1,1)(df['date'])                  
1577836800000000000 <class 'int'>
1578441600000000000 <class 'int'>
...
```

without it, it passes `int` to the function, with it, it passes the pandas time objects:

```
In [69]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:foo(x,[3,8]), 1,1)(df['date'].astype(object))   
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2020-01-08 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
...
```

So this use of `qualifies` works:

```
In [71]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:qualifies(x,[3,8]),1,1)(df['date'].astype(object))                                                                     
Out[71]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: date, dtype: object
```

## object dtype

For the main iteration, `np.vectorize` does

```
      ufunc = frompyfunc(_func, len(args), nout)
      # Convert args to object arrays first
        inputs = [array(a, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=object)
                  for a in args]
        outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
```

That explains why `vectorize` with `otypes` works - it is using `frompyfunc` with an object dtype input.  Contrast this with `Out[37]`:

```
In [74]: np.array(df['date'], dtype=object)                                     
Out[74]: 
array([Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-08 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-01-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-22 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2020-01-29 00:00:00')], dtype=object)
```

And an alternative to specifying `otypes` is to make sure you are passing object dtype to `vectorize`:

```
In [75]: np.vectorize(qualifies, excluded=[1])(df['date'].astype(object), [3, 8])                                                                      
Out[75]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

This appears to be the fastest version:

```
np.frompyfunc(lambda x: qualifies(x,[3,8]),1,1)(np.array(df['date'],object))
```

or better yet, a plain Python iteration:

```
[qualifies(x,[3,8]) for x in df['date']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @rpanai answer on the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577442/numpy-vectorization-messes-up-data-type) is still the best. Here I share my tests:

```
def qualifies(dt, excluded_months = []):
    if dt.day < 5:
        return False
    if (dt + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - dt).days < 5:
        return False
    if dt.month in excluded_months:
        return False
    return True

def new_qualifies(dt, excluded_months = []):
    dt = pd.Timestamp(dt)
    if dt.day < 5:
        return False
    if (dt + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - dt).days < 5:
        return False
    if dt.month in excluded_months:
        return False
    return True

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='7D', periods=12000)})
```

apply method:

```
%%timeit
df['qualifies1'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: qualifies(x, [3, 8]))
```

385 ms ± 21.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

conversion method:

```
%%timeit
df['qualifies1'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: new_qualifies(x, [3, 8]))
```

389 ms ± 12.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

vectorized code:

```
%%timeit
df['qualifies2'] =  np.logical_not((df['date'].dt.day<5).values | \
    ((df['date']+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1)-df['date']).dt.days < 5).values |\
    (df['date'].dt.month.isin([3, 8])).values)
```

4.83 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Thanks for replying @Adrea. that's surely a large performance gain! I find it a lot less readable tbh, but I guess that's the trade-off between performance and readability.

Comment: @ElRudi. You just haven't learned how to read it yet. You will with enough practice though.

Comment: I agree, much less readable. Maybe one can try to fix it by splitting the problem into 3 parts and use three different columns, still the `.apply` method is much more elegant (more pythonic at least)

Answer (score 0):

Just as in the original question, I can "solve" the problem [by forcing the incoming argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581117/2302262) to be a `pandas` datetime object, by adding `dt = pd.to_datetime(dt)` before the first `if`-statement of the function.

To be honest, this feels like patching-up something that's broken and should not be used. I'll just use `.apply` instead and take the performance hit. Anyone that feels there's a better solution is very much invited to share :)

Comment: Is this approach really faster than the `.apply` one performance-wise? In my tests it turns out it is actually slower

Comment: I just tried and interestingly, it's not. I've tried with short (53) and long (5300 rows) dataframes, the times are a few % apart at most. It's interesting because if you look at my answer to the original question (linked in this answer), you see that it's twice as fast when the function-to-be-vectorized takes only one argument.

Comment: I manage to also fix this by adding ``dt = pd.Timestamp(dt)`` too since the attribute ``day`` comes from from the ``Timestamp`` class. It seems that ``vectorize`` accesses ``df["date"].values`` quietly or something. It probably deserves to open a github issue.

Comment: I think the problem might be that numpy `vectorize` can only work with numpy's datatypes and, since a `Timestamp` object is not, it can not work.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is a `numpy` function.  It is not `pandas` aware!