# convert 'datetime64[D]' to month number

Tags: python

date_index = np.arange('2015-01-01','2016-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
hello
I want to convert the date_index to the month name but I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: Do you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648774/get-year-month-or-day-from-numpy-datetime64

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
months = date_index.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1
```

Comment: And after getting month number, you can ```import locale   import calendar 
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')   print(calendar.month_name[1])``` (where ```1``` is just month number). Pandas would also be helpful.